# Get DOM element in react native

Tags: react-native

I am making a `js` based spreadsheet engine using React Native. The library uses a global document (`document.getElementById`) object to associate DOM properties. However, I get the following error.

```
Can't find variable document
```

I know that there is no "document object" in React Native. Is there a way to access the DOM via the `document` object so that I can include my `js` file in the app. Alternatively, is there any other method for the same?

I have tried with `WebView` but the `document` object is still undefined.

Answer (score 3):

DOM is only relevant in web development. In react native you have no DOM, there is a different visual tree that is created via React components.